# Multiple usb microphones/input in android?

Tags: android, audio, usb, oboe

I am using `getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager` to get manager and then looking into `microphones` or `getDevices(GET_DEVICES_INPUTS)` to see what is available.

I have connected powered 4 port usb hub and to it 3 simple usb audio interfaces. I tested on macbook I see them there all at once as 3 separate sound inputs.

On tablet **Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite** and phone **Xiaomi Mi 9T** I can see always just one, no matter what I do.

So to me this looks like android hardware is not capable to handle multiple usb audio interfaces ?

Is this true for all android devices even latest ones with latest android ? Its hard to find any info on this. I just need multiple inputs not outputs.